# how to create quick access menu using css

Tags: css

My apologies if I am asking for the code but pls let me know how to create quick access menu just like salesforce using only css. 
I know how to create a dropwdown using css and display it inside an visual force page but I am unable to toggle it(hide/show).

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is very related to Visualforce or Salesforce. But here is a codepen example for you to take a look at: https://codepen.io/surjithctly/pen/pLDwe You should be able to figure out by following this.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested - you can look at the Lightning Design System for the new Global Navigation CSS:

[SLDS Global Navigation](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/global-navigation/)